# hyperlinks to a separate PDF document

Tags: xetex, hyperref, hyperlink, hypertarget

I am trying to figure out a way to create hyperlinks between PDF documents.

Here's an **MWE**:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{Sample target}
\hypertarget{n21}{}
target of link in volume1/pdf/mwe.pdf
\newpage
\section{Sample hyperlink}
Please click on \hyperlink{n21}{n° 21 ;} and have a look at note 21 in volume one 
of this book (in file volume1/pdf/mwe.pdf) for more information.
\end{document}
```

In the above example the link and the target live in the same document.

How would I do the same thing when the link and the target live in two different documents?

Evidently I would need to tell pdf viewer 'whatever' that the target is in another pdf file.

Typical use case: hyperlinks between two different volumes of the same book.

Or to put it differently… starting with the above MWE, after replacing all occurrences of '**volume1'** by '**volume2**' and splitting my MWE into two separate files with section: 'Sample target' in one file and section: 'Sample link' in the other… How would I code/modify the `\\hyperlink{} macro`in my MWE to reference the 'other' pdf file?

Are such acrobatics even possible with **hyperref** or do I need to use a different package?

N.B. I am currently testing on a *nix-type (linux) file system¹ but the syntax should (obviously) be OS-agnostic.

¹ to clarify: after running xelatex on the source files the resulting directory tree with the pdf's would look something like:

```
../book/volume1/pdf/volume1.pdf
../book/volume2/pdf/volume2.pdf
```

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xr-hyper

Answer (score 2):

If you have

```
\hypertarget{n21}{text}
```

in `volume2.pdf`

then

```
\href{volume2.pdf#n21}{n21 in volume2}
```

in volume1 will create a link that opens the file and jumps to the destination.

It assumes that both files are in the same directory.
It also assumes that the destination names have not be manipulated: xelatex/xdvipdfmx "optimize" destinations to numbers, and so break the link. They need `\special{dvipdfmx:config C 0x10}` to avoid this.

The xr-hyper creates such cross references with \ref/\label.